google extension - permition errors
I need a Chrome extension to activate  speech to type in the win, for that, i try to create one but I get some errors from permission can we check that, please where I'm making the mistake
manifest
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Instagram Speech-to-Text",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Converts speech in Instagram videos and reels to text using Windows 11 Voice Typing",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["*://*.instagram.com/*"]
}

popup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Instagram Speech-to-Text</title>
    <script src="popup.js" defer></script>
    <style>
        body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding: 10px; }
        button { margin: 5px; }
        #transcribedText { width: 100%; height: 100px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Instagram Speech-to-Text</h1>
    <textarea id="transcribedText" placeholder="Transcribed text will appear here..."></textarea><br>
    <button id="startRecording">Start Recording</button>
    <button id="stopRecording" disabled>Stop Recording</button>
</body>
</html>


popup.js
document.getElementById('startRecording').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Focus on the text area
  const transcribedTextArea = document.getElementById('transcribedText');
  transcribedTextArea.focus();

  // Send message to background to start voice typing
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "startVoiceTyping" }, (response) => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.error("Error:", chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      } else {
          console.log("Voice Typing activated:", response.status);
      }
  });

  // Disable the start button and enable the stop button
  document.getElementById('startRecording').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('stopRecording').disabled = false;
});

document.getElementById('stopRecording').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // You can implement stop recording functionality if needed
  console.log("Recording stopped.");

  // Reset button states
  document.getElementById('startRecording').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('stopRecording').disabled = true;
});


contenr.js
function activateVoiceTyping() {
  // Simulate pressing "Windows logo key + H" using robotjs
  const robot = require('robotjs');

  // Press the Windows logo key
  robot.keyToggle('command', 'down');

  // Press the "H" key
  robot.keyToggle('h', 'down');
  robot.keyToggle('h', 'up');

  // Release the Windows logo key
  robot.keyToggle('command', 'up');
}

chrome.input.onKeyDown.addListener((event) => {
  if (event.key === 'H' && event.altKey && event.ctrlKey) {
    // Hotkey detected, activate Voice Typing
    activateVoiceTyping();
  }
});

ActivateVoiceTyping.ps1
//# ActivateVoiceTyping.ps1

//# Add necessary type for simulating key presses
//Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'

//# Simulate the 'Windows logo key + H' to activate Voice Typing
//[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{LWIN}h")  # Correctly simulate Windows key + H

# ActivateVoiceTyping.ps1

# Add support for calling user32.dll to simulate keyboard input
Add-Type @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    public class Keyboard {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

        public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
        public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
        public const int VK_LWIN = 0x5B;
        public const int VK_H = 0x48;
    }
"@

# Simulate Windows key press and release
[Keyboard]::keybd_event([Keyboard]::VK_LWIN, 0, [Keyboard]::KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, [UIntPtr]::Zero)
[Keyboard]::keybd_event([Keyboard]::VK_H, 0, [Keyboard]::KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, [UIntPtr]::Zero)

# Release Windows key and H key
[Keyboard]::keybd_event([Keyboard]::VK_H, 0, [Keyboard]::KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, [UIntPtr]::Zero)
[Keyboard]::keybd_event([Keyboard]::VK_LWIN, 0, [Keyboard]::KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, [UIntPtr]::Zero)


runVoiceTyping.bat
@echo off
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%~dp0ActivateVoiceTyping.ps1"

not : i add the powershield and auto hotkeydash
all I am looking for is  when i open the Instagram reels page record some of the sound as text via  activate the Windows speech-to-type app which is already in the Windows system.
this is how my app have to look (: 
but i got alot ot permition error in the console of chrome .

There's no such thing as chrome.input.onKeyDown, chatgpt is hallucinating as usual. Use the standard addEventListener('keydown', .....

(: usulay he do that
